# How to make multiple ID's for one element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find out how to format for an element that is different throughout my site. For example, the background for my  list in my navigation bar is green. I am making a  list down in the body for listing multiple items. It is automatically taking all of the formatting in my nav bar and putting it in my list like it should.

My question is how to make a ID or CLASS to take away the formatting used in my nav bar to make my own formatting for this list in my body. I tried looking up youtube videos and googling for this but all I could find was formatting for multiple selectors at the same time.

How do I override the CSS for my nav bar for the list in the body?

for my  class I tried doing  and then ul.amazon01 { background-color: none; and it does not work.

My nav bar HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="box1"> 
        <ul id="nav01">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropbtn"># Menu</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="index.html"></a>
                        <a>#</a>
                        <a href="#</a>
                        <a href="#</a>
                        <a href="#</a>
                        <a href="#</a>
                    </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: green;
  border: 3px solid darkgreen;
}
```

This is the  I want to use in my body

```
<ul class="amazon01">
    <li>#</li>
    <li>#</li>
    <li>#</li>
    <li>#</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.amazon01 {
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: `none` is an invalid value for `background-color`, so it is ignored. Use `transparent` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend styling HTML Tags at all. Instead you should only aplply styling by using classes.

So instead of

```css
ul {
  ...
}
```

use

```css
.nav01 {
  ...
}
```

You can reuse your class multiple times, if you want, but by using classes you have full control where your styling is apllied and there is no need for overwriting styles.

If you have more than one tag with overlapping styling you can use following syntax:

```css
.nav01, .amazon01 {
  styling that is applied for both classes...
}

.nav01 {
  detailed styling... 
}

.amazon01 {
  detailed styling... 
}
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused, how am I supposed to use the <ul> / <li> tags to make my list then? Sorry I am a noob

Comment: Nevermind you are right. I apparently am blind lol. I understand what you are saying now. Thank you for the answer